# Override how a BsonRecord fills in its fields

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I would like to extend the BsonRecord class to handles some of its fields when they are filled in. I'm trying to do it by extending the setFieldsFrom... methods, but it doesn't seem to work...

Here is the code I have :

```
trait NodeBsonRecord[MyType <: BsonRecord[MyType]] extends BsonRecord[MyType]
{
    self: MyType =>

    override def setFieldsFromDBObject(dbo:DBObject) =
    {
      super.setFieldsFromDBObject(dbo)
      println("setFieldsFromDBObject")
    }
    override def setFieldsFromJSON(json:String) =
    {
      val out = super.setFieldsFromJSON(json)
      println("setFieldsFromJSON")
      out
    }
    override def setFieldsFromJsonString(json:String) =
    {
      val out = super.setFieldsFromJsonString(json)
      println("setFieldsFromJsonString")
      out
    }
    override def setFieldsFromJValue(jval:JValue) =
    {
      val out = super.setFieldsFromJValue(jval)
      println("setFieldsFromJValue")
      out
    }
    override def setFieldsFromReq(req:Req) =
    {
      val out = super.setFieldsFromReq(req)
      println("setFieldsFromReq")
      out
    }
}
```

So when I request for a Record (using MongoRecord.find()), I expect to see a "setFieldFrom..." thing, but nothing is printed out...

Anybody can tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo seems to use [setFieldsFromDBObject](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/persistence/mongodb-record/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/mongodb/record/BsonRecord.scala#L138) in BsonMetaRecord as part of find, which iterates through each field and calls setFromAny.

Comment: Yes, and it is called by the instance of the field in setFieldsFromDBObject : `def setFieldsFromDBObject(...) = BsonMetaRecord.setFieldsFromDBObject(this, ...)`. So, I assume that my overriding of it should do the job, but it doesn't...
I found another way to solve my problem so I don't need to do this anymore, but if someone wishes to try that, it could be useful...